# How to pass Fabric API Key and Secret to cordova-plugin-firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have been using the `cordova-fabric-plugin` for years. As a link to your Fabric project, you can pass to this plugin two parameters : an API Key and an API Secret like this :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=XXX --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=xxx
```

Which result in an updated `config.xml` file like this :

```
<plugin name="cordova-fabric-plugin" spec="^1.1.10">
      <variable name="FABRIC_API_KEY" value="XXX" />
      <variable name="FABRIC_API_SECRET" value="xxx" />
</plugin>
```

Now, I need to install Firebase to my project via the `cordova-plugin-firebase`, which has is own Fabric framework included. But I can't find a way to pass those same parameters dynamically. 
I've been doing some research inside both plugins code :

A sample from the `cordova-fabric-plugin`'s `ios-helper.js file`:

```
    // Read and parse the XCode project (.pxbproj) from disk.
            // File format information: http://www.monobjc.net/xcode-project-file-format.html
            var xcodeProject = xcode.project(xcodeProjectPath);
            xcodeProject.parseSync();

            // Build the body of the script to be executed during the build phase.
            var script = '"' + '${SRCROOT}' + "/\\\"" + utilities.getAppName(context) + "\\\"/Plugins/cordova-fabric-plugin/Fabric.framework/run " 
+ pluginConfig.apiKey + " " + pluginConfig.apiSecret + '"';
```

And now from the `cordova-plugin-firebase`'s `helper.js` file :

```
// Read and parse the XCode project (.pxbproj) from disk.
    // File format information: http://www.monobjc.net/xcode-project-file-format.html
    var xcodeProject = xcode.project(xcodeProjectPath);
    xcodeProject.parseSync();

    // Build the body of the script to be executed during the build phase.
    var script = '"' + '\\"${SRCROOT}\\"' + "/\\\"" + utilities.getAppName(context) + "\\\"/Plugins/" + utilities.getPluginId() + "/Fabric.framework/run" + '"';
```

**==>** The parameters are not used anymore! I get the following error when trying to push a new release to Fabric :

> Fabric API key not valid. Your Fabric run script build phase should
>   contain your API key: ./Fabric.framework/run INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY
>   INSERT_YOUR_BUILD_SECRET

I can type the Key and Secret manually to XCode but I need a dynamic workaround to industrialize the process.

Anyone with a solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I think the plugin is broken. Did you ever find a solution?